# How to delete rows in Excel dynamically

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

### Background Info:

I am attempting to return an Excel sheet using C# and EPPLUS that will show the user which rows need attention. The cell that contains the sku has its background set to red and any other cells that are checked are set to yellow.

That works.

### Problem:

I am having problems deleting the rows that don't cause any errors. I'm not sure if deleting a row will make the next row's row number the same as the deleted one or if it will stay the same. I am currently getting an *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* error.

### Code:

```
//Loops through the errors datatable pulling the sku's from there and entering them into an array. Then loops through each row on the excel sheet and checks to compare against sku array. If it is not in there, that row is deleted
int[,] errorList = new int[errors.Rows.Count, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < errors.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     errorList[i, 0] = Convert.ToInt32(errors.Rows[i][0]); //SKU                                    
     errorList[i, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(errors.Rows[i][1]); //Brand
     errorList[i, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(errors.Rows[i][2]); //Secondary Identifier
}
//Loop through the Excel sheet
for (int i = 2; i <= rowCnt; i++)
{
     //Loop through the error array
     for (int j = 0; j < errorList.Length/3; j++) 
     {
          //Column 3 = SKU
          if ((worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value).ToString().Equals(errorList[j,0].ToString()))
          {
               worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
               worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
               //If brand caused an error
               if (errorList[j,1] == 1)
               {
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
               }
               //If secondary identifier(Destination) caused an error
               if (errorList[j,2] == 1)
               {
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 22].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 22].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
               }
               break;
          }                                        
     }
     //Check to see if the cell's background colour is red. If it isn't, delete the row    
if(!worksheet.Cells[i,3].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb.Equals(Color.Red.ToString()))
         {
             worksheet.DeleteRow(i);
             i--;
         }
    }
```

### Question:

How should I go about deleting rows in Excel using EPPlus?

*Question aid:*

- Delete row 5
- Row 6 stays as row 6 
  OR
- Row 6 becomes row 5, 7 becomes 6 and so on

Comment: When you delete row 5, row 6 becomes row 5. That is why a loop that deletes rows should always start at the bottom and work towards the top.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at looping through the Excel sheet from bottom to top